# Dynamically create json based on list of keys in Python

Tags: python, json

I have multiple lists of string which I want to be my keys for my JSON.

For example, I have the following lists:

```
['dev', 'aws', 'test']
['dev', 'azure', 'test']
['prod', 'aws', 'test']
```

Based on that, I want to create the backbone of my JSON with these values representing the keys.

This is the output I would like:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "aws": {
            "test": ""
        },
        "azure": {
            "test": ""
        }
    },
    "prod": {
        "aws": {
            "test": ""
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that I need to create it dynamically, as the keys are not static and could change.

I can't figure out a way to create this dynamically and can't seem to find help on the web, so if you have any idea on how to handle this case, it would really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does all the list in length of 3?

Comment: let's say the **3**rd list is `['azure', 'dev', 'azure']` - what should be the final output?

Comment: @Reznik Yes, it should always be the same length.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It will create another key for `azure` along with the root keys (`"azure": { "dev": { "azure": ""}}`) (if that make sense)

Comment: What happens when there comes in a new key on third level. Say if now you get `['dev', 'aws', 'test2']` Will test2 replace test in first dict object?

Comment: @MohitC It will create a new key called `test2` next to the one called `test`, so that `dev/aws` will have two children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def add_elem(json, keys, val):
    parent = json
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        if k not in parent:
            parent[k] = {}
        parent = parent[k]
    parent[keys[-1]] = val


d = {}
paths = [
    ['dev', 'aws', 'test'],
    ['dev', 'azure', 'test'],
    ['prod', 'aws', 'test']
]

for keys in paths:
    add_elem(d, keys, "")

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'dev': {'aws': {'test': ''}, 'azure': {'test': ''}}, 'prod': {'aws': {'test': ''}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible recursive solution that should work for varying lengths of fields and be flexible for future keys or additional fields or lists.

the function takes a dictionary and a list, it will take the first tiem from the list and if it doesnt exist in the dictionary it will create it, if there are more items left in the list it will allocate a new dict to the key and then pass this new dict and the remaining list items back to its self.

if there are no items left in the list it will create the last item as a key with a string value of ''.

```
def build_dict(my_dict, my_list):
    key, *data = my_list
    if key not in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] = {} if data else ''
    if data:
        build_dict(my_dict[key], data)

my_lists = [
    ['dev', 'aws', 'test'],
    ['dev', 'azure', 'test'],
    ['dev', 'azure', 'preprod', 'more', 'long', 'length'],
    ['prod', 'aws', 'test'],
    ['prod', 'short']
]

my_dict = {}
for list_data in my_lists:
    build_dict(my_dict, list_data)
print(my_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'dev': {'aws': {'test': ''}, 'azure': {'test': '', 'preprod': {'more': {'long': {'length': ''}}}}}, 'prod': {'aws': {'test': ''}, 'short': ''}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
data = [
    ['dev', 'aws', 'test'],
    ['dev', 'azure', 'test'],
    ['prod', 'aws', 'test']
]
result = {}
for k,v, m in data:
    result.setdefault(k, {}).setdefault(v, {}).update({m: ''})

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'dev': {'aws': {'test': ''}, 'azure': {'test': ''}},
 'prod': {'aws': {'test': ''}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we treat the input as a list of lists:

```
lol = [
    ['dev', 'aws', 'test'], 
    ['dev', 'azure', 'test'], 
    ['azure', 'dev', 'azure']
]
```

Then you can use the following:

```
d = {}
for lst in lol:
    use = d # make sure that for each list we refer to the base dictionary
    *head, tail = lst # unpack so we can...
    for key in head: # ... loop over each except the trailing key
        use = use.setdefault(key, {}) # default to a dict and point `use` to the result
    use[tail] = '' # assign blank string to last element
```

This then gives you `d` as:

```
{
    "dev": {
        "aws": {
            "test": ""
        },
        "azure": {
            "test": "",
            "test2": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

lists = [
    ['dev', 'aws', 'test'],
    ['dev', 'azure', 'test'],
    ['prod', 'aws', 'test']
]

paths = defaultdict(dict)
for k1, k2, k3 in lists:
    if k2 not in paths[k1]: paths[k1][k2] = {}
    paths[k1][k2].update({k3: ""})

pprint.pprint(dict(paths), width=4)
```

The output:

```
{'dev': {'aws': {'test': ''},
         'azure': {'test': ''}},
 'prod': {'aws': {'test': ''}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
dict = {}
for i in lists:
    try:
        dict[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]] = ""
    except KeyError:
        try:
            dict[i[0]][i[1]] = {i[2] : ""}
        except KeyError:
            dict[i[0]] = {i[1]: {i[2]: ""}}
```

Output:

```
{'prod': {'aws': {'test': ''}}, 'dev': {'azure': {'test': ''}, 'aws': {'test': ''}}}
```

Comment: @prashantrana, not at all. Check user's requirements in comment, list is always going to be of len 3

Comment: "Dynamically create json based on list of keys in Python" Not dynamic

Comment: he doesnt say it will be 3, he just says all lists will be the same length. it always better to design a flexible solution that can grow with change.

Comment: @prashantrana, dynamic means taking values as per the dynamic data. Do you see anything hardcoded here? Check user comments on question, list is always going to be on len 3

Comment: @ChrisDoyle completely agree with you

Comment: @MohitC I have to say that whereas your answer is correct, a more dynamic one is indeed gonna be preferred (ie: if tomorrow we want to add another key, your code should be modified compared to a code with a more dynamic approach). But thanks for your answer anyway :)